# How to provide proper weight to align the view properly in table android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am using a heading where I need to place seven headings with correponding values.

But the first column has image with two text which is troubling to fit inside the table.

I given weight but it's troubling in aligning with other views. Everytime whenever i change one view say for eg: 5th column, sixth column gets rearranged.

I used a list followed by row.

In the main xml, I used Titles.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Profile icon-->
        <include layout="@layout/common_profile_layout" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Laporan Aktivitas"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorUserGroup" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dafatar_filter"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curve_corner_change_day"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="Pilih Tanggal"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:text="06/13/2017"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/route_plan_about_icon"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:src="?attr/info_drawable" />
        </RelativeLayout>
// here is where the title starts.
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/totalId"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nbd_title"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:weightSum="6">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/siteId"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/site"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXXXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/twoG"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.65"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/threeG"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".65"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fourG"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".65"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retailerId"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idealId"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rel1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="6">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.2"
                    android:background="@color/colorLightGray" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.65"
                    android:background="@color/colorLightGray" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".65" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".65"
                    android:background="@color/colorLightGray" />

                <View

                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorLightGray" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycleViewIdNbd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingTop="18dp" />
        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

then in row.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="6">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1.9">


            <com.hutchison.h3i.newangie.customviews.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_num"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@string/route_plan_default_number"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_tiny_small_nine" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="SE A"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorUserGroup"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtretailerId"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXXXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_3"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_4"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But my output looks as ,

[image]

But actual output is,

[image]

You can clearly see where in my output, align is getting mismatch and not properly fitting. I tried to align but I couldn't achieve it properly.

Comment: Your root layout weightsum must be equal to total childs layout_weight.

Comment: so what should i do for that to align? @MohamedMohaideenAH

Comment: Your need the desired output like in second image. Or you have tried something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..
This will work...

Main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Profile icon-->
        <!--  <include layout="@layout/common_profile_layout" />-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Laporan Aktivitas"
                android:textColor="?attr/scrimAnimationDuration" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dafatar_filter"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/setting"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="Pilih Tanggal"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:text="06/13/2017"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_16" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/route_plan_about_icon"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:src="?attr/constraintSet" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        // here is where the title starts.

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/totalId"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/crop_image_menu_rotate_left"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/siteId"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/site"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXXXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/twoG"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/threeG"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fourG"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retailerId"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idealId"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rel1">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycleViewIdNbd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingTop="18dp" />
        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="10">
        <!--colorLightGray-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGray">


            <com.hutchison.h3i.newangie.customviews.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_num"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="appname"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="SE A"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtretailerId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXXXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hello @Pragya. Yes it's working but that color is not applying for entirely.How to use that view line in main xml?

Comment: use drawble xml file for background of " rel1 "- Linearlayout....
Mention shape and solid color accordingly....

Comment: Yes it worked. Can you please tell how or on what basis you are adjusting and arranging the layouts. For eg: if its 3 columns, i need to give totalSum as 3, and share equal weight for all 3 column as 1?

Comment: Its not compulsory to share equal weight for all the columns...It just depends upon the required width of the particular column...

Plz check out this small example  .....

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/android-layout-weight-weightsum-ramasamy-kasiviswanathan/

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout with **weightsum** property.
Example if you want to set each child items in the linear parent to same size simply set android:layout_weight ="1" for all childs and set android:layout:width = "0dp". No need to use weightsum property.

**Important** to set android:layout:width="0dp" if you want child view weight property works.

You can set one view to fill remaining space in layout. Have a look at example https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html.

As your required basis from second image try this below code:

**Main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/totalId"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/nbd_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/siteId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.2"
        android:text="Total"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/site"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="XXXXX"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twoG"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threeG"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fourG"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/retailerId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idealId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Row.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2.2">


            <com.hutchison.h3i.newangie.customviews.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_num"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@string/route_plan_default_number"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_tiny_small_nine" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="SE A"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorUserGroup"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtretailerId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXXXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtidealId_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

So your total child layout_weight property match to parent weightsum. thn use same property to parent & child row to get actual result.
Hope it helps..!

Comment: Hello @Mohamed. This same weight is applicable for view line also. (ie which I used in main.xml). ie i need to use the same weight which you used in row for view line?

Comment: Yes you can use same weight for view also.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the weights mentioned for the corresponding columns (heading and rows) are same.
Also, all the weights of the child elements must add up to the weightSum of the parent element.